# how to copy editing file in same location but different name with VIM

Tags: vim, macvim

I am trying to find a combination of commands, macro or a plugin to copy the file I am editing in VIM (actually macvim) to the same location but with a different name. I am sure this could be achieved with a simple:

```
 !cp $CURRENT_FILE_PATH $NEW_PATH
```

but I don't know what variables to use nor the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:saveas %:p:h/new_name`

For more information:

```
:h :saveas
```

Comment: Note that `:saveas` command sets the filename of the current buffer to the new file (passed as an argument).  This means that after its execution you will be editing the copied file, not the original!  To save the file to a new location and continue editing that very file (and not a just written copy) use `:write` command.

Answer (score 3):

```
:!cp % %:h/new_name
```

- `%` expands to the current filename
- `%:h` expands to the current filename's directory

To learn more:

- `:help expand()`
- `:help filename-modifiers`

Comment: +1 good answer.  For windows, it'd be `!copy "%:p" "%:p:h/new_name"`.  Notice the "" these let you use this on files with spaces, etc. in the name.